# Swap cards in deck

Tags: java, swap

How to swap the position of two cards in the deck of `ArrayList<Card>`?

```
public class Deck
{
    private ArrayList<Card> deck;

    public Deck()
    {
        deck = new ArrayList<Card>();
    }

    public void addCard(Card cardToAdd)
    {
        deck.add(cardToAdd);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please try to explore your options before asking. I believe you are writing this class yourself?

Comment: Are you sure this is C++ - Looks like Java

Comment: This is java code (unless he is asking for a conversion to C++ this is mistagged). Also is there something against posting homework questions without some sort of tag (which this likely is...)?

Answer (score 0):

The supplied code is Java, so we'll go with Java.

Add a method, called swapCards like so:

```
public void swapCards (int indexA, int indexB)
{
    Card temp = deck.get (indexA);
    deck.set(indexA, deck.get (indexB)); 
    deck.set(indexB, temp); 
}
```

Now, some thing to think about:

1. What happens if indexA and indexB are beyond the size of the deck, how should the class behave?
2. Is there a better way to design the class? Are card indicies the best parameters to use here, could we do something else?

Comment: It says: array required, but java.util.ArrayList<Card>found.
You are using syntax here that suggests that you are trying to access an array element. The variable you refer to is not an array, though.

Comment: Fixed that, I've been programming in python for too long now.

Comment: if (deck.size()>indexA && deck.size()>indexB) then ....
otherwise message error.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: So, in Java, the best way to do the 'message error' is to have the method throw an Exception, see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalArgumentException.html

Comment: Also, try and implement a shuffle method - that would teach you a lot. 

public void shuffle () { .. }

Comment: public void shuffle()
    {
        int rand1;
        int rand2;
        Random randomGenerator = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < deck.size(); i++) {

            // pick a random index between 0 and size of the deck - 1
            rand1 = randomGenerator.nextInt(TIMES_TO_SHUFFLE);
             rand2 = randomGenerator.nextInt(TIMES_TO_SHUFFLE);

            // swap rand1 and rand2
            Card temp = deck.get (rand1);
            deck.set(rand1, deck.get (rand2)); 
            deck.set(rand2, temp); 
        }
    }

Comment: but it was java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException; Index:8; size:4(in java.util.ArrayList)